# Symfony Doctrine ManyToMany add custom join field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entites : `Cart` and `Item`, the relation is configured with `ManyToMany` because a cart can have multiple items, and a items can be in multiple carts.

So I have a link table `item_cart` with `item_id` and `cart_id`.

How can I work with quantity with this ? For example if I need to add 800 items with `id = 2` to the cart with `id = 5` ?

Is this possible to add a field quantity in the link table ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by making the relationship itself to an entity. This entity would be called `CartItem` or `CartItemLink`.

The association changes from `ManyToMany` between `Cart` and `Item` to two associations `ManyToOne` and `OneToMany`:

`Cart` - *ManyToOne* - `CartItem` - *OneToMany* - `Item`

Now you can add additional fields to your `CartItem`, like a `$quantity` field as mentioned in your question.

So this would look something like this:

The `CartItem`:

```
class CartItem {

    /** MANY-TO-ONE BIDIRECTIONAL, OWNING SIDE
     * @var Cart
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Cart", inversedBy="cartItems")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cart_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $cart;

    /** MANY-TO-ONE BIDIRECTIONAL, OWNING SIDE
     * @var Item
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Item", inversedBy="cartItems")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $item;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $quantity;

    //.. setters + getters
}
```

The `Cart`:

```
class Cart {

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** ONE-TO-MANY BIDIRECTIONAL, INVERSE SIDE
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\CartItem", mappedBy="cart")
     */
    private $cartItems;

    //.. setters + getters
}
```

The `Item`:

```
class Item {

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** ONE-TO-MANY BIDIRECTIONAL, INVERSE SIDE
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\CartItem", mappedBy="item")
     */
    private $cartItems;

    //.. setters + getters
}
```

I didn't add an id to `CartItem` because it can have either a composite key (`$item_id` + `$cart_id`) or a natural key and that I leave up to you.

[Don't forget to initialize your `$cartItems` `ArrayCollection` inside the constructor](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/best-practices.html#initialize-collections-in-the-constructor) of `Item` and `Cart`.

Comment: Are they any performance disadvantages with custom join entities vs. the Doctrine collections?

Comment: If you don't add any additional columns the database structure is the same (one join table with two identifier columns). You will have more control though on what to eager/lazy load and you can add additional data to the relationship. In general this `one-to-many/many-to-one` relationship is considered best practice (see also comment [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#title.1.8) about many-to-many). Find more by [googling the topic](https://google.com/search?q=doctrine+many-to-many+vs+one-to-many%2Fmany-to-one)